# How to download a file from URL with credentials in windows application C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, download, desktop-application

Hy guys! I need a function to download a file from a website, before downloading it will be redirected to login page. So I have to authenticate myself as well.
The function will be used in the window app on a desktop.
Function arguments:

- link to the file
- path to save a path to local disk
- use login
- password

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: What do you mean by proving yourself? Do you need to enter your account password, or log in directly with a code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you an example:

The core idea is: verify the account password after clicking download, and download if it is correct.

Use DialogResult to return the result of the verification.

Use SaveFileDialog to select the location to save.

Enter the URL you want to download into the text box.

Main window code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            login f2 = new login();
            while (true) {
                f2.ShowDialog();
                if (f2.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) {
                    Download();
                } else if (f2.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
                    MessageBox.Show("Verification Failed");
                break;
            }
            f2.Close();
        }

        //Download function
        public void Download() {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            //Set the title of the save file dialog
            sfd.Title = "Please select the file path to save.";
            //Initialize the save directory, the default exe file directory
            sfd.InitialDirectory = Application.StartupPath;
            //Set the type of saved file
            sfd.Filter = "Text file|*.txt|Audio file|*.wav|Picture file|*.jpg|All files|*.*";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                //Get the path to save the file
                string filePath = sfd.FileName;
                //save
                try {
                    WebClient client = new WebClient();
                    client.DownloadFile(textBox1.Text, filePath);
                } catch (WebException webEx) {
                    Console.Write(webEx.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

[image]

Login window code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
    public partial class login : Form {
        public login() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            //Personal test database
            string myconn = @"Data Source = (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog = Test; Integrated Security = True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconn);     
            string sql= $"select * from Test.dbo.demoAccount where userid='{ AccountTb.Text}' and password='{PassTb.Text}'";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)//Satisfy the user name and password are consistent, enter the next interface
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            } else {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            }
            conn.Close();
}
    }
}
```

[image]

Schematic diagram of correct operation:

[Test Url](https://photo.16pic.com/00/53/26/16pic_5326745_b.jpg)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it help you？

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your detailed response but it seems you verifying credentials from your own database, but in my scenario credentials have to be verified by the website (not own by me).

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding what you mean. Do you mean automatic login in the code?

Comment: You can use `httpwebrequest` to log in to the target website. If possible, please provide the account and password id of the target login form.

Comment: Can you give me some code snippets to better help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [WebClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.credentials?view=net-5.0) tool?
You can set credentials and write the response in a file.

```
    try {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", securelyStoredPwd);
        client.DownloadFile(linkToTheFile,pathToTheFile);   
    } catch (WebException webEx) {
        Console.Write(webEx.ToString());
    }
```